# NoClassDefFoundError: Error in running applet in appletviewer

Tags: java, html, applet

I just ran into trouble in applet execution in webpage: An error dialog popped up: 
[image]

The calculator is my class name and Exercise4 is the folder that contains it. I am sure that the html file and the calculator.class are in the same folder named Exercise4. What is happening in here?

Comment: The class is not in the classpath at Runtime.

Comment: How could that be? I made sure that they are in the same folder and this error is different from the "class not found" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up directories and packages. If you class has the name `x` and resides in the package `y` your codebase *must not* point to the directory `y`. Instead the codebase must point to the *parent directory* of `y` and the class name must be specified as `y.x`.

So in your case you seem to have specified a directory `Exercise4` which ought to be the package name and an applet class of `calculator` which is wrong as it ignores the package name.

As said you have to specify the parent directory of the package directory structure, i.e. the parent directory of `Exercise4`, as the codebase and specify `Exercise4.calculator` as the applet class.

Note that package names should be lowercase and class names be uppercase by convention. Adhering to conventions helps other people help you on problems, e.g. by finding the problem faster.